# Java unable to get the correct value of a modified Int

Tags: java, swing, methods

so i have three classes, one is the main GUI, a class for methods and a class for a log in window.

in my method class i have

```
public int IsLoggedOn = 0;

public int returnLoggedinValue (){
    return  this.IsLoggedOn ;
}
public int setLoggedOn(){
    System.out.println("logged on ");
    return 1;
}
```

in my log in window action listener for the button i have

```
methodWin meth = new methodWin ();
methodWin.IsLoggedOn = methodWin.setLoggedOn();
System.out.println("logged in value "+methodWin.IsLoggedOn);
```

then back in the main GUI for the end of the action listener that initiated the log in window i have

```
methodWin meth = new methodWin ();
int ar = meth.IsLoggedOn;
System.out.println("ar is "+ ar);
if (ar==1){
    System.out.println("user is logged in");
    jTextField1.setEnabled(true);
    jButton1.setEnabled(true);
}
```

the problem that i am having is that if i print out the value of IsLoggedOn from the log in window it has correctly changed it to "1" but then back in the main GUI when i check the value of IsLoggedOn i get "0"

sorry quite new to this whole Java thing, not too sure why the change is not being seen

Comment: First of all "Stick to [Java Coding Convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) ". Secondally you are creating new instance of methodWin class for getting value which will not work.

Comment: @HarryJoy you are correct. Main problem is two different object here.

Comment: declaring the int as static worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  methodWin.IsLoggedOn = methodWin.setLoggedOn();
```

In log you are setting the value of IsLoggedOn to 1;
but in main GUI you are not doing it.

declare IsLoggedOn as static

```
 public static int IsLoggedOn = 0;
```

I hope this would help

Answer (score 1):

In each case you initialise a new instance of methodWin, only in the log in window will you change the initial value from 0 to 1, which is not done. In the main GUI the initial value is not touched so it remains as 0.

I assume you will somehow want to initialise only one instance of methodWin and get both sets of code to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 public class MethodWin{
     private int isLoggedOn=0;
     private static MethodWin objectMethodWin = new MethodWin();
     private MethodWin(){}
     public static MethodWin getInstance(){
         return objectMethodWin;
     }
     public void setIsLoggedOn(int value){
         this.isLoggedOn=value;
     }
     public int getIsLoggedOn(){
         return this.isLoggedOn;
     }
 }
```

In your log in window action:

```
 MethodWin meth = MethodWin.getInstance();
 meth.setIsLoggedOn(1);
 System.out.println("logged in value "+ meth.getIsLoggedOn);
```

In main GUI:

```
 MethodWin meth = MethodWin.getInstance();
 int ar = meth.getIsLoggedOn();
 System.out.println("ar is "+ ar);
 if (ar==1){
     System.out.println("user is logged in");
     jTextField1.setEnabled(true);
     jButton1.setEnabled(true);
 }
```